# Perl diamond operator in double while loop hangs

Tags: perl, while-loop, diamond-operator

In my Perl script I have a double infinite while loop. I read lines from a file with the diamond operator. But somehow if my script reaches the last line of the file, it does not return undef, but hangs forever.

If I reduced my code to a single while loop this did not happen. So I wonder if I am doing something wrong or if this is a known limitation of the language. (This is actually my first perl script.)

Below is my script. It is meant to count the size of DNA sequences in fasta files, but the hanging behavior can be observed with any other file with multiple lines of text.

Perl version 5.18.2

Invoked from the commandline like `perl script.pl file.fa`

```
$l = <>;
while (1) {
    $N = 0;
    while (1) {
        print "Get line";
        $l = <>;
        print "Got line";
        if (not($l)) {
            last;
        }
        if ($l =~ /^>/) {
            last;
        }

        $N += length($l);
    }
    print $N;
    if (not($N)) {
        last;
    }
}
```

I put some debug print statements so that you can see that the last line printed is "Get line" and then it hangs.

Comment: Please show us some representative input data and the according log output.

Comment: @Corion You can use any text file as input. The output is actually just what I want. That's not the problem. The problem is that the <> hangs after the last line. Just run the script with any file and you will see it will hang at the "print "Get line"", indicating that the <> just won't continue.

Comment: Hmm - I guess it just works as designed - you never check for `eof()` and try to read one more line from the default input. If you use `<>`, it will fall back to reading from STDIN once `@ARGV` has been exhausted. See https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readline.html . I don't understand what your logic is, but I guess you want a `last if eof;` before trying to read another line.

Comment: @Corion From the documentation it says `each call reads and returns the next line until end-of-file is reached, whereupon the subsequent call returns undef` So I did not expect it to fall back to STDIN, but expected it to return undef. That's what `if (not($l)) {last;}` is supposed to do. Check if the line is undef and than exit the while loop.

Comment: @Corion `last if eof` before `<>` will do the trick. But I still not understand why it wouldn't just return undef. Is it maybe that `<>` will return undef once but the second time it will move on to STDIN, because that is what happens. Only the second time it hangs, the first time it still outputs undef.

Comment: Yes, but `<$foo>` is different from `<>` , which goes through all items on `@ARGV`, and if you invoke it one more time after that, it will wait on reading from `STDIN`

Comment: @Corion But what is $foo now?

Comment: @Corion `<>` or `<ARGV>` only falls back to STDIN if `@ARGV` is empty; if it's started reading from files it will only read each file passed. [perlop](https://perldoc.pl/perlop#I/O-Operators) has more details. I suspect the hanging is due to the while(1) loop rather than waiting for STDIN.

Comment: You will want to check `not defined $l`, not `not $l`, since the latter will get confused if a line contains nothing or only a 0 before the EOF. The normal idiom for this is `while (my $l = <>)`, which is a particular construct that checks defined rather than truthiness due to some magic, and ends once there are no more files to read or STDIN received EOF.

Comment: @Grinnz You are correct about the explicit defined check. But I don't think it is infinite looping, because it also stops printing anything. While in an infinite loop it should still do the print statements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to Perl.

The issue with your code is that you have no way of escaping the outer loop. `<>` will return `undef` when it reaches the end of the file. At this point your inner loop ends and the outer loop sends it back in. Forcing further reads causes `<>` to start looking at `STDIN` which never sends an EOF, so your loop continues forever.

As this is your first Perl script I'm going to rewrite it for you with some comments. Perl is a fantastic language, you can write some great code, however mostly due to it's age there are some older styles which are no longer advised.

```
use warnings; # Warn about coding errors
use strict; # Enforce good style
use 5.010; # Enable modernish (10 year old) features

# Another option which mostly does the same as above.
# I normally do this, but it does require a non-standard CPAN library
# use Modern::Perl;

# Much better style to have the condition in the while loop
# Much clearer than having an infinite loop with break/last statements
# Also avoid $l as a variable name, it looks too much like $1
my $count = 0; # Note variable declaration, enforced by strict
while(my $line = <>) {
    if ($line =~ /^>/) {
        # End of input block, output and reset
        say $count;
        $count = 0;
    } else {
        $count += length($line);
    }
}

# Have reached the end of the input files
say $count;
```

Answer (score 0):

try "echo | perl script.pl file.fa".

works for me with same "problem" in my code.

gets EOF from stdin.